# Can I Use an x86 Android kernel on Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, android, tablet

I received a tablet as a gift. It has a Cherry Trail SoC, meaning it's x86. I was wondering if I could simply rip the kernel from the stock Android ROM that comes with the tablet and use that with an Ubuntu install. If someone knew the answer to this, that would be great, as I couldn't find one online. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the newer kernel that comes in Ubuntu? You may have other problems with getting traditional Ubuntu running on such a tablet though, as Android tablets (even the x86 ones) tend to have Android-specific boot methods.

Comment: I imagine you could try one of the images [here](https://system-image.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/stable/ubuntu/generic_x86/)

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for the suggestion! I've actually already tried those. They're unfortunately missing the necessary drivers.

Comment: Oh well, you could always try to use an Android kernel in Ubuntu. Your bound to learn something in the process. Sorry i have no information on that, nor do I have the hardware available to test it on so you've got an advantage there.

Comment: @ElderGeek Alright, thanks for the response! I'll post a followup after I try it.

Comment: I look forward to seeing your results! ;-)